# Google Sheets App Script timing out and time based trigger not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is all of my code from a function that I have been working on for a while. Essentially I am trying to create a load of class analysis packs (I am a teacher) and print a google sheet as a PDF and then change a drop down (effectively changing the page and data) and then print again until all of the class codes in the drop down have been completed. The function works really well but the issue I have is that it will take longer than 6 mins to run as there are about 150 packs to create. I have looked into triggers and created a time based trigger which should start a few minutes after it has timed out. It seems to successfully create the trigger but the trigger never actually runs. Is this the correct approach? If so can anybody spot why its not working? Any feedback would be amazing as this has been driving me crazy!

```
function CreateClassPacks() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp

  var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();
  var REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT = 100000
  var MAX_RUNNING_TIME = 340000

  // Getting the date and putting it into the format we want
  var d= new Date();
  var dateStamp = d.getDate()+"/"+d.getMonth()+"/"+d.getYear();

  // Getting a token which will give me the authorisation I need
  var request = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers":{"Authorization": "Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},    
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  // This is the key for the spreadsheet I am working on and then it gets fetched
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var getKeys = ss.getSheetByName("Settings");
  var mainSSKey= getKeys.getRange("B1").getValue();
  // Key for the folder we will save the documents into
  var folderCPKey = getKeys.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var foldersave=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderCPKey);
  var fetch='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+mainSSKey+'/export?format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=false'

  // This section gets all of the class codes from whichever sheet we choose.
  // The first variable will need changing to whichever number sheet holds the codes.
  var classCodeSheetNum = 0
  var classCodeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[classCodeSheetNum]
  var maxRowNum = classCodeSheet.getLastRow()-1;
  // This variable must contain the correct column for the class codes
  var dataRange = classCodeSheet.getRange(1, 1, maxRowNum, 1);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(data)

  // This must be the sheet number for the class analysis packs
  var sheetNum = 4
  var newTrig = false

  // This will loop through my data variable which contains all the class codes
  for (var r=0; r<(data.length)-1; r++) { 
    for (i in data[0]) {

      var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
      var startRow= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_row');
      var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
      if(currTime - startTime >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME) {
        if (newTrig == false){
                  ScriptApp.newTrigger("CreateClassPacks")
                 .timeBased()
                 .at(new Date(currTime+REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT))
                 .create();
                 newTrig = true
          break;
          }
        } else {
          // This sets the value of A2 on the analysis sheet to the value from the data structure
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[sheetNum].getRange('O1').setValue(data[r][i]);

          var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var sheet = source.getSheets()[sheetNum];

          // This gets the value from A2 and sorts out the name of the file
          var classCode = data[r][i]
          var name = classCode + " " + dateStamp + ".pdf";

          // This checks if the file already exists which will hopefully fix any timeout issues
          var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name)
          var chk = file.hasNext()
          if (chk === false) {

              // This hides all the sheets except for the one I am printing
              for(var w=0; w< sheetNum;w++)
              {
                sheet = source.getSheets()[w];
                sheet.hideSheet();
              }

              // This PDFs the page and has a timeout delaying the access requests so I don't get the annoying errors
              var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetch, request);
              pdf = pdf.getBlob().setName(name);
              Utilities.sleep(4000);
              var file = foldersave.createFile(pdf)

              // This shows all the sheets that I previously hid
              for(var q=0; q< sheetNum;q++)
              {
                sheet = source.getSheets()[q];
                sheet.showSheet();
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[This shows that the trigger seems to be created even though it doesn't run the function again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDxnm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here but I think your code could be a lot quicker.  For one thing create the `var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` and then use ss everywhere else.  All create `var allSheets=ss.getSheets()` and then use `allSheets[i]` instead of 'ss.getSheets()[i]`.  That section for i in data[0] makes no sense to me.  The data is one column wide.  All I would hide all of the sheets before the loop and then if necessary show the one that I'm printing if you have to.  Hiding and showing sheets takes time.  Try not to do it. I have gone through the code a bit but admittedly I don't have any context so I doubt that it runs.  But I tried to take as much out of the loop as possible and you should too.  You may find that you can get it to run in the allotted time.

```
function CreateClassPacks() {
  var dateStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var getKeys=ss.getSheetByName("Settings");
  var mainSSKey=getKeys.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var folderCPKey=getKeys.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var foldersave=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderCPKey);
  var fetch='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+mainSSKey+'/export?format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=false'
  var classCodeSheetNum=0;
  var classCodeSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[classCodeSheetNum]
  var maxRowNum=classCodeSheet.getLastRow()-1;
  var dataRange=classCodeSheet.getRange(1, 1, maxRowNum, 1);
  var data=dataRange.getValues();
  var sheetNum=4;
  var newTrig=false;
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++){
    allSheets[i].hideSheet();
  }
  var srcrng=allSheets[sheetNum].getRange('O1');
  var sheet=allSheets()[sheetNum];
  for (var r=0;r<data.length-1;r++){ 
    srcrng.setValue(data[r][0]);
    var classCode = data[r][i]
    var name=classCode + " " + dateStamp + ".pdf";
    var file=DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
    var chk=file.hasNext()
    sheet.showSheet();
    var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetch, request);
    pdf = pdf.getBlob().setName(name);
    var file = foldersave.createFile(pdf);
    sheet.hideSheet();
  }
}
```